# Function in a function in java

Tags: java, arrays, function

Is there a way to use the first function in the second one to create a double array with random numbers?

```
public  static  int[]  build1(int size) {
    int[] arr = new int[size];
    for (int i=0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
        arr[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 127);

    return arr;
}

public  static  int[][] build2(int row, int col) {
    int[][] arr2 = new int[row][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2[i].length; j++) {
            arr2[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * 127);
        }
    }
    return arr2;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would assume the following should work.

```
public static int[][] build2(int row, int col) {
    int[][] arr2 = new int[row][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        arr2[i] = build1(col);
    }
    return arr2;
}
```